# How to make RecyclerView with different types of items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have list with different types of items. How to make RecyclerView in this case?
I have User class. In this class I have variable address Address type. Address class also has own variables.
I tried to do as I was advised, but it does not work correctly. only user data is displayed. the address data is not output.

my first item class:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
```

getters, setters
}

my seconf item class:

```
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String suite;
    private String city;
getters, setters
}
```

my adapter class:

```
   public class ResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static int TYPE_ADDRESS = 1;
    private static int TYPE_USER = 2;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<User> users;

    public ResultAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ADDRESS){
            return new AddressViewHolder (layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
        }else if(viewType == TYPE_USER){
            return new UsersViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
        }else return new AddressViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
if (holder instanceof AddressViewHolder){
Address address = new Address();
((AddressViewHolder) holder).city.setText(address.getCity());
} else if (holder instanceof UsersViewHolder){

    final User user = users.get(position);
    ((UsersViewHolder) holder).name.setText(user.getName());

}
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (position==1){
          return TYPE_ADDRESS;
      }else
          return TYPE_USER;
    }

public static class AddressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
final TextView city;
    public AddressViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        city = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    }
}

   public static class  UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
       final TextView name;
        public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I think it is what I need.

Comment: If my answer helped you , kindly mark it as answer . Thanks

Comment: @ Akki, I did as you suggested, with some changes. 
but now only user data is displayed. These addresses are not displayed.    
Please, see, I changed my question.

Comment: Two reasons : One that inside of `getItemViewType` you are returning type address if position is 1 . Also you have address inside of user class , so you need to explain the question on what is it that you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

```
        public class GenericAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
                private static int TYPE_ADDRESS = 1;
                private static int TYPE_USER = 2;
            
                private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
                private List<User> users;
                private Context context;
            
                public GenericAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
                    this.users = users;
                    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    this.context = context;
                }
            
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                   if(viewType == TYPE_ADDRESS){
                       return AddressViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
                   }else if(viewType == TYPE_USER){
                       return UsersViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
                   }else return AddressViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));
                }
            
                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                    if(holder instanceof AddressViewHolder){
                        /*Your binding */
                    }else if(holder instanceof UsersViewHolder){
                        /*Your binding */
                    }
            
                }
            
                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return users.size();
                }
            
                @Override
                public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                    /*Please specify your logic here of selecting the type optionally you can use the position to query the data and decide on it*/
                    return (position % 2 == 0 )? TYPE_ADDRESS : TYPE_USER;
                }
            
                 class AddressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            
                    public AddressViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                    }
                }
            
                 class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            
                    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                    }
                }
            
            }
```